# Ruby on Rails routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm very new to ruby on rails! I'm basically trying to create an application that allows organizations to create events! so far a user is able to create an organization but when they try to create an event I get this **error : Routing Error undefined local variable or method `params' for EventsController:Class**

I've looked over everything and tried to find something similar all over stack overflow if you have any suggestions please let me know!

events controller:
      before_action
      @organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])

```
  def index
    @events = @organization.events
  end

  def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end


  def new
    @event = Event.new
  end

  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    @event.organization = @organization

    if @event.save
      redirect_to organizations_path
    else
      render 'new'
      flash[:notice] = "Event not saved"
    end
  end

  def edit
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @event.destroy
    redirect_to organizations_url
  end

  private  
  def event_params

    params.require(:event).permit(:user_id, :organization_id, :event_size, :date, :name, :description, :location)

  end

end
```

organizations controller

```
  def index
    @organizations = Organization.all
    # @organization = Organization.find(params[:id])

  end

  def show
    @organization = Organization.find(params[:id])
    @events = @organization.events
  end

  def new
    @organization = Organization.new
  end

  def create
    @organization = Organization.new(organization_params)
    if @organization.save
      redirect_to organizations_path

    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  private
  def organization_params
    params.require(:organization).permit(:organization_id, :name, :description, :location, :volunteer_position)
  end
end
```

events index.html.erb

```
    <h1>Events index</h1>

<% @events.each do |event| %>

<div class="events_name">


  <p><%= event.name %></p>
  <p><%= event.description %></p>
  <p><%= event.location %></p>
<br/>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

routes

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'home#index'
  resources :timeslots
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :users
  resources :home
  resources :home, only: [:index]
  resources :organizations do
  resources :events
  end
```

form for event

```
<%= form_for @event do |f| %>

<div>
 <%= f.label :name %>:
 <%= f.text_field :name %><br />
</div>
<div>
 <%= f.label :description %>:
 <%= f.text_field :description %><br />
</div>
<div>
 <%= f.label :location %>:
 <%= f.text_field :location %><br />
</div>
<div>
    <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :date%>
     <%= f.date_select :date,
         { order: [:month, :day, :year],
           prompt: [ day: 'Select day', month: 'Select month', year: 'Select year' ]} %>
   </div>

<br>
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: is `EventsController` inheriting from `ApplicationController`?

Comment: no it doesn't.. should it(sorry for the late reply!)?

Comment: Can you post the params passed from View to controller? It will be there in logs. Also, post the code for event form

Comment: just posted the code for the events form.. not sure how to post the params passed from view to controller? could you direct me n how to find them?

Comment: Yes, it should, otherwise it won't work as a controller

Answer (score 0):

Based on your response to the first comment, you probably need to inherit from `ApplicationController`, which is where `params` get defined under the hood.

As you build your app, all controllers need to inherit from `ApplicationController` in some way. Sometimes, this means a nested controller would just inherit from a parent controller that inherits from `ApplicationController`.

E.g.,

```
class ParentController < ApplicationController
end

class Parent::ChildController < ParentController
end
```